# Unable to resize the image

Tags: html, image, jsp

i am using the below code to resize an image . i only want to resize the image and not trim the image ... i want the whole image just smaller size and i am using the below code :

`<div style="background: url(image_url);"></div>`

i don't want to use `<img>` tag because i cant iterate the images with it because i can't put the java variable in `<img src =""`

`<img src="<%=img%>"/>` --> this dosent work as it gives a white_space error

Comment: Link the code you used to try to resize this image in your answer please.

Comment: You should use background-size property
Here is js fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/emprL3ht/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background: url(image_url) no-repeat; background-size: contain;"></div>
```

Using the CSS3 property:

`background-size: contain;` - the image is streched to fit the container without cutting it off

Answer (score 1):

You can put the img in the img tag, if the jsp expression is not working, you can use expression language ${youimageref}.

Then give the image tag a class definition like resizer and from css you can control the size, for example:

```
img.resizer {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
```

Usingg percent will resize the image when you change the size of the browser window as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
img.resizer {
    max-width:(actual size of images)
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
```